# Session should expire after inactivity in superset

Tags: apache-superset

I'm currently using Superset 0.28.1
Session should expire after inactivity.

1) Tried by setting SUPERSET_WEBSERVER_TIMEOUT, SUPERSET_TIMEOUT parameter in config.py.

2) Tried with below commands  while starting the server :: 
superset runserver -t 120 
superset --timeout 60
gunicorn -w 2 --timeout 60 -b  0.0.0.0:9004 --limit-request-line 0 --limit-request-field_size 0 superset:app

Answer (score 2):

Put `PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME` config to your config file. The value is second.

eg. 
`PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME = 60`  means expire after inactivity 1 minute

Comment: We have tried this options using link                                       
https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/5149                                     User never log out from application after idle session.User gets redirected to Login Page after activity.

We also write custom code in flask_appbuilder/security/views.py

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
session.permanent = True
app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=5)